# Can't figure out the reason why my components with onClick prop aren't working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to make a very simple test screen. It should change the value of "a" to 1 but the button simply won't work.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';

export default function HomeScreen() {

  const [a, setA] = useState(0)

  return (

    <View style={styles.main}>
      <Text>{a}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity title="BUTTON" style={styles.button} onPress={()=>setA(1)}>
        <Text>SIR</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I've also tried the Button component, but none of the components which require the onClick prop work.

Comment: Can you include ``styles``?

Comment: It is still just an empty file.

Comment: Where are you rendering ``HomeScreen``?

Comment: I've been using expo, and I've tried to run it on a web browser and on the Expo Go app, and the button doesn't work in either of them

Comment: TochableOpacity doesn't have a title prop.

Comment: I tried it, and it works. Maybe your styles is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this looks quite good... I also tried an adapted version of your code on the reactnative.dev page: https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity. You can also go there and copy paste the code i attached below and try it out by yourself. It works fine.

The only adaption I made there is, that I removed your "styles" component. So I assume the bug is anywhere inside this component. Maybe you disabled the TouchableOpacity component or something like this.

Feel free to share the content of your styles component if you need more support.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';


export default function HomeScreen() {

  const [a, setA] = useState(0)

  return (

    <View>
      <Text>{a}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity title="BUTTON" onPress={()=>setA(a+1)}>
        <Text>Press here</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just realized my code does, in fact, work by testing it on Expo Snack, but for some reason when I start it through the terminal and open it on Expo Go or on my browser, the button doesn't work. Do you know what could be causing this issue?